# Regex match - can't work it out

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

I've got a string that I need to parse into an array in PHP. The string looks something like this:

```
(Key: ALL_HTTP)(Value:HTTP_HOST:10.1.1.1 )(Key: ALL_RAW)(Value:Host: 10.1.1.1:80 )(Key: APPL_MD_PATH)(Value:/ROOT)(Key: AUTH_TYPE)(Value:)(Key: AUTH_USER)(Value:)(Key: AUTH_PASSWORD)(Value:)(Key: LOGON_USER)(Value:)(Key: REMOTE_USER)(Value:)
```

The number of "key/value" pairs could be unlimited but is usually about 30-40 per string.

I've been playing with preg_match and a variation of an example from PHP.net - something like this:

```
preg_match('/(\S+): (\S+)/', $string, $result);
```

That gets me back the first key as $result[0] but doesn't help for the rest.

If anyone could help me with a proper expression that would be fantastic. I'd also appreciate any good reading resources for splitting strings with PCRE.

Thanks all!

Comment: what you mean for "parse into array"? you want to convert keys to the key of an associative array and value as the associated value?

Comment: Sorry Gianps - yes that's what I mean. So the (Key: ALL_HTTP)(Value:HTTP_HOST:10.1.1.1 ) would become something like array("ALL_HTTP" => "HTTP_HOST:10.1.1.1")

Comment: If you output always comes with the brackets grouping keys and values, you could skip regex entirely and just remove the first and last bracket, and then split on `)(` and take the resulting array in pairs to create a new `key => value` array (and tnen you'd just trim hte string & strip the first 'Key:' or 'Value:'.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @mathematical.coffee! I gave it a try and made a hacky solution with it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of

```
preg_match_all('/\(([^:)]+):\s*([^)]*)\)/',
        "(Key: ALL_HTTP)(Value:HTTP_HOST:10.1.1.1 )(Key: ALL_RAW)(Value:Host: 10.1.1.1:80 )(Key: APPL_MD_PATH)(Value:/ROOT)(Key: AUTH_TYPE)(Value:)(Key: AUTH_USER)(Value:)(Key: AUTH_PASSWORD)(Value:)(Key: LOGON_USER)(Value:)(Key: REMOTE_USER)(Value:)",
        $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($out as $pair) {
    echo "ALL: ".$pair[0]."\n";
    echo "KEY: ".$pair[1]."\n";
    echo "VAL: ".$pair[2]."\n";
}
```

You probably don't need the ALL lines.

Based on your sample string, you might like this regex better:

```
'/\(Key: ([^)]+)\)\(Value:([^)]*)\)/'
```

Comment: @Borodin - He didn't specify output and I based my example on what he had been using for his regex, which he indicated worked fine for the first matches.  Nevertheless, I agree with you that it is an unexpected way of matching.

Comment: I mean it doesn't pick up the `Value` fields at all

Comment: @Borodin - Ah. I see now.  Fixed.  Thanks.  I had not noticed the empty values nor the lack of a space after Value:.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression `/\(Key:\s*(.*?)\)\(Value:\s*(.*?)\)/` will match all the key/value pairs in the string

This program builds an array `$data` with the each key/value pair related in an element

```
$str = '(Key: ALL_HTTP)(Value:HTTP_HOST:10.1.1.1 )(Key: ALL_RAW)(Value:Host: 10.1.1.1:80 )(Key: APPL_MD_PATH)(Value:/ROOT)(Key: AUTH_TYPE)(Value:)(Key: AUTH_USER)(Value:)(Key: AUTH_PASSWORD)(Value:)(Key: LOGON_USER)(Value:)(Key: REMOTE_USER)(Value:)';

$list = preg_match_all('/\(Key:\s*(.*?)\)\(Value:\s*(.*?)\)/', $str, $data);
$data = array_combine($data[1], $data[2]);

var_dump($data);
```

**output**

```
array(8) {
  ["ALL_HTTP"]=>
  string(19) "HTTP_HOST:10.1.1.1 "
  ["ALL_RAW"]=>
  string(18) "Host: 10.1.1.1:80 "
  ["APPL_MD_PATH"]=>
  string(5) "/ROOT"
  ["AUTH_TYPE"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["AUTH_USER"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["AUTH_PASSWORD"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["LOGON_USER"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REMOTE_USER"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```